# How to avoid both windows open in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

Using my First script, I create a layout as I need. Now I want to use this layout in the second script and add widgets to the frame. Face the following problem: Both the First and second program windows will open simultaneously, I want to open/ show my second program window only.  How to resolve it?

**First script**

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QApplication, QFrame, QHBoxLayout, QSizePolicy

class MsgBox111(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.frame_main = QFrame()
        self.frame_main.setObjectName("ob_frame_main")
        self.frame_main.setStyleSheet("QFrame#ob_frame_main{background-color:green}")

        self.frame_left_top = QFrame()
        self.frame_left_top.setObjectName("ob_frame_left_top")
        self.frame_left_top.setStyleSheet("QFrame#ob_frame_left_top{background-color:skyblue}")
        self.frame_left_top.setMinimumSize(600, 340)

        self.frame_left_bot = QFrame()
        self.frame_left_bot.setObjectName("ob_frame_left_bot")
        self.frame_left_bot.setStyleSheet("QFrame#ob_frame_left_bot{background-color:lightgreen}")
        self.frame_left_bot.setFixedSize(600, 60)

        self.frame_right = QFrame()
        self.frame_right.setObjectName("ob_frame_right")
        self.frame_right.setStyleSheet("QFrame#ob_frame_right{background-color:rgb(230,220,150)}")
        self.frame_right.setFixedSize(200, 405)

        self.lay_main = QHBoxLayout()
        self.lay_main.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.lay_main.setSpacing(8)
        self.lay_left = QVBoxLayout()
        self.lay_left.setSpacing(8)
        self.lay_left_top = QVBoxLayout()
        self.lay_left_top.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.lay_left_bot = QHBoxLayout()
        self.lay_left_bot.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.lay_right = QVBoxLayout()
        self.lay_right.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.lay_overall = QHBoxLayout()
        self.lay_overall.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.lay_overall.setSpacing(5)

        self.lay_left_top = QVBoxLayout(self.frame_left_top)
        self.lay_left_bot = QHBoxLayout(self.frame_left_bot)
        self.lay_right = QVBoxLayout(self.frame_right)
        self.lay_main = QHBoxLayout(self.frame_main)

        self.lay_left.addWidget(self.frame_left_top)
        self.lay_left.addWidget(self.frame_left_bot)

        self.lay_main.addLayout(self.lay_left)
        self.lay_main.addWidget(self.frame_right)

        self.lay_overall.addWidget(self.frame_main)

        self.setLayout(self.lay_overall)

        frame_right_sizehint = self.lay_left.sizeHint()
        self.frame_right.setFixedSize(260, frame_right_sizehint.height())
        self.frame_main.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Fixed, QSizePolicy.Fixed)
```

**Second script**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLineEdit
from layour_sample_001 import *


class MsgBox222(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ss = MsgBox111()
        self.ss.show()

        self.tb = QLineEdit()
        self.ss.lay_left.addWidget(self.tb)
        self.ss.setLayout(self.ss.lay_left)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainwindow = MsgBox222()
    mainwindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: You can have `MsgBox222` derive from `MsgBox111`.  You call the base class `__init__` and then add your additional widgets.

Comment: First of all, you have two *scripts*, not two "programs", they're **not** the same thing; please, be more careful with terminology, it *is* important. Then, your question is very confusing: 1. If you don't want to show the first message box, why do you call `show()` then? 2. What do you mean by "I want to use this layout in the second [script]"? Please, try to make yourself more clear.

Comment: using my first scripts, I create my basic structures/ layouts. I want to use this layout in my second script and add widgets to that layout. @musicamante

Comment: @tckraomuqnt so you want to use the same layout structure you create for MsgBox111, and add other widgets to it for a "specialized" version of that class that would be MsgBox222?

Comment: yes, You are correct @musicamante

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to properly *subclass*.
After calling the `__init__` for the superclass, you can access all inherited attributes of that class and instance: you have a fully constructed `MsgBox111` instance that you can then extend according to your needs.

```
class MsgBox222(MsgBox111):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.tb = QLineEdit()
        self.lay_left.addWidget(self.tb)
```

<sup>I *strongly* suggest you to do some more research and careful studying on the main aspects of OOP, including classes, instances, inheritance, attributes and subclassing, as knowledge of these fundamental topics is mandatory.</sup>